# Multi-State Toggle Button

Tags: android, user-interface, button, togglebutton

In the app I've been working on, I would like to have a multiple-state (in my case, three) toggle button, instead of the two that `ToggleButton` provides. I've tried to start my own that extends `Button`, following the `CompoundButton` source, but quite honestly reading over its source got a bit overwhelming.

Is there a way to do a three-state toggle button using just a selector xml or something, or perhaps another method I haven't thought of? I'm rather at a loss of how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can certainly define a selector to use as a background that has three entries. The question is what button attributes you can use for the selector. You can have two boolean attributes, say A and B, and define the selector in terms of A, B, and default. (A && B will satisfy A, so more properly they could be thought of as A, !A && B, and !A && !B.) You can overload existing attributes (selected, focused, etc.) or, more elegantly, define your own custom attributes using the recipe described [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo).

Comment: Looking at the thread you linked: I understand step 1, but 2 I have some questions about. In creating a new view, would it be better to extend View, Button, or something else? And are there other methods I should be overloading besides the constructors and onCreateDrawableState()? My apologies if these are basic, this is my first real app.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working! Thank you for the push in the right direction, I appreciate it.

Comment: @moonfire is your code proprietary? I'm trying to create a tri-state toggle button too, and would like to see some other solutions to wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: @JohnMetta Sorry for the late answer, I should check here more often. If you still need help, I just made a post about it at [link](http://goo.gl/WQoGA). Or if you just want to download example source code: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3448760/AndroidAsILearnIt/CustomButtonExample.zip). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 20):

I implemented a multi-state toggle button, the source code is [here](https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton)

This is how it looks:

[image]

And it's quite easy to use it:

```
<org.honorato.multistatetogglebutton.MultiStateToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/mstb_multi_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    mstb:values="@array/planets_array" />
```

In your activity:

```
MultiStateToggleButton button2 = (MultiStateToggleButton) this.findViewById(R.id.mstb_multi_id);
button2.setOnValueChangedListener(new ToggleButton.OnValueChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(int value) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + value);
    }
});
```

Comment: how did you customized it like in the picture? In your docs you didn't mention any custimizations.

Comment: That's an old version, try searching for older commits. But basically you'll have to modify the background drawables.

Comment: @jlhonora thank you for this great code! I was wondering if it's possible to make a transition between toggles, instead of jumping straight from one button to the other, is there a way to transition between them?

Comment: @jlhonora If I pass value `Yes` from Activity A to B where the toggle button is, how can I set the state of the toggle button with value `Yes` as checked ?

Answer (score 14):

You can create a custom ImageButton to achieve this, you need 3 different images in this case.
You can also add more states if you want.

```
public class FlashButton extends ImageButton {

    public enum FlashEnum {
        AUTOMATIC, ON, OFF
    }

    public interface FlashListener {
        void onAutomatic();
        void onOn();
        void onOff();
    }

    private FlashEnum mState;
    private FlashListener mFlashListener;

    public FlashButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        //Sets initial state
        setState(FlashEnum.AUTOMATIC);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        int next = ((mState.ordinal() + 1) % FlashEnum.values().length);
        setState(FlashEnum.values()[next]);
        performFlashClick();
        return true;
    }


    private void performFlashClick() {
        if(mFlashListener == null)return;
        switch (mState) {
            case AUTOMATIC:
                mFlashListener.onAutomatic();
                break;
            case ON:
                mFlashListener.onOn();
                break;
            case OFF:
                mFlashListener.onOff();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void createDrawableState() {
        switch (mState) {
            case AUTOMATIC:
                setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_auto);
                break;
            case ON:
                setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on);
                break;
            case OFF:
                setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off);
                break;
        }
    }


    public FlashEnum getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    public void setState(FlashEnum state) {
        if(state == null)return;
        this.mState = state;
        createDrawableState();

    }

    public FlashListener getFlashListener() {
        return mFlashListener;
    }

    public void setFlashListener(FlashListener flashListener) {
        this.mFlashListener = flashListener;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are making people lazy ;)

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `RadioGroup` and style radios inside?

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" //center text
        android:text="text"
         />
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Chip is a very good native option.

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
      android:id="@+id/chip_group"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:singleSelection="true">

      <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
           android:id="@+id/first_chip"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Todo"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:checkable="true"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
           app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

           <!-- Second Chip -->
           <!-- Third Chip -->

   </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

---

```
binding.chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, i -> 
    when (i) {
        binding.firstChip -> {
            binding.firstChip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent)
        }
        else -> {} 
    }
}
binding.firstChip.isChecked = true  //default
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207173/5279996)