# how to customize toggle button with three options android

Tags: android, switch-statement, togglebutton

I try to make custom switch with three options , how to make it like this picture[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post here:  [Multi-State Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823851/multi-state-toggle-button)

There are two solutions:

**1. Using a library** - Probably can't adapt it to suit your image requirements.

**2. Extending an ImageButton**
    - Seems fairly simple and may work for you.