# How to do a 4 states toggle button?

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I'm reading some post over this site to do a multi state toggle button. The most interesting post is this: [Multi-State Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823851/multi-state-toggle-button) but the maximum states are 3, onAutomatic, onOn, onOff. I need 4 states.

I want to put a button with 4 possible images, MAN ICON, BLACK MAN ICON, WOMAN and BLACK WOMAN.

I don't know how to reach this. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: You are wrong. it supports any number of states.

Comment: Where I can find info about that? Thanks

Comment: on the github  there is a sample, which you should have watched
https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the above states as :

1. MAN

   - MAN ICON
   - BLACK MAN ICON
2. WOMAN

   - WOMAN
   - BLACK WOMAN

now create a simple button with checked and unchecked state as Man And Woman and divide it into further two using selected and unselected states which will give you four states.

- Checked-selected
- checked-unselected
- unchecked-selected
- unchecked-unselected