# how to make toggle with 3 selection in android?

Tags: android, toggle, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

My question is very simple. Is there any way to make a toggle button which will provide user to select 3 options like **ON**,**OFF**,**NEUTRAL**?

I search a lot, but other options are there like use spinner but I wanna customize toggle button. Any idea how to achieve that?

**Thanks a lot in advance & for you valuable time**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-State Toggle Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823851/multi-state-toggle-button)

Comment: The first thing I can think of is a RadioGroup with 3 RadioButtons. With some eventual graphics to mimick a 3 state switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this third party library, it has more than two selectors and I think that it satisfies your requirement.

https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton

Regards!

Comment: this is what i was looking for