# Android Material Chip - ChipGroup with singleSelection doesn't work adding chips dynamically

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

I am using [Material Chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) for first time.

**Problem:** 
I am adding chip dynamically using following code. Please check I wrote `app:singleSelection="true"` which is important for me. **Even though its selecting multiple chips at a time.**

I want to select **only one chip with tick mark** at a time.

**XML Code:**

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/categoryChipsView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:chipSpacing="10dp"
                app:singleSelection="true"
                app:itemSpacing="15dp"
                app:singleLine="true">
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

**Java Code:**

```
private void addChipView(String chipText) {
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_chip_view, null);
    Chip chip = child.findViewById(R.id.chip);
    chip.setText(chipText);
    chip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, ((Chip) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    // This is ChipGroup view
    binding.categoryChipsView.addView(child);
}
```

**row_chip_view.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_check"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
    app:chipIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
    app:textEndPadding="5dp"
    app:textStartPadding="5dp" />
```

[image]

What I have tried statically, I have pasted view of `row_chip_view.xml` as child of **ChipGroup** in main xml and Its working fine. I can select only one chip at a time.

```
           <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/categoryChipsView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:chipSpacing="10dp"
                app:singleSelection="true"
                app:itemSpacing="15dp"
                app:singleLine="true">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
                    android:id="@+id/chip"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_check"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
                    app:chipIconTint="@android:color/white"
                    app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
                    app:textEndPadding="5dp"
                    app:textStartPadding="5dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
                    android:id="@+id/chip2"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_check"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
                    app:chipIconTint="@android:color/white"
                    app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
                    app:textEndPadding="5dp"
                    app:textStartPadding="5dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
                    android:id="@+id/chip3"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_check"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
                    app:chipIconTint="@android:color/white"
                    app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
                    app:textEndPadding="5dp"
                    app:textStartPadding="5dp" />

            </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[image]

BUT I WANT IT DYNAMICALLY.

> ### Update: New Scenario
>
> First of all I have added four chips in XML within `ChipGroup` and
>   after that tried to add another three chips PROGRAMATICALLY in same
>   `ChipGroup`. The first four chips is allow to select only one but last
>   three chips allow me to select multiple. Very Weird.

Do let me know If I am missing anything.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53518090/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod Its seems slight different as I want to select only one chip every time.

Comment: [Then you need to use `app:singleSelection="true"` or `setSingleSelection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup#setsingleselection) in your `ChipGroup`

Comment: Tried. Not working. You can try to add simply 3-4 chips to `ChipGroup` programatically and check. @NileshRathod

Comment: Are you sure about this line *binding.categoryChipsView.addView(child);*? you should add the chip to the chipGroup, instead you are adding a view (child not chip)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes, there is no other method like `addChip`

Comment: Try to use: `Chip chip = (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_chip_view, chipGroup, false); //....    chipGpRow.addView(chip)`.

Comment: @PratikButani I am able to replicate the issue. Just **remove** the `id` in your chip layout. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Remove** in your `row_chip_view.xml` the **android:id** attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    .../>
```

And in the `addChipView` use:

```
private void addChipView(String chipText) {
    Chip chip = (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_chip_view, chipGroup, false);
    chip.setText(chipText);
    //...

    // This is ChipGroup view
    chipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its silly unknown mistake and unable to find out.

Comment: I tried this answer but it worked only after I added ID for the Chip dynamically like that:

`chip.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead `onClickListener` use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` this works for me in combination with `singleSelection="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Add integer id before adding Chip to ChipGroupd

```
    Chip chip = (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_chip, chipGroup,
  false);
            chip.setId(i);
            chip.setText("str");
            chipGroup.addView(chip);
```